# C# throws exception and redirect back to controller with RedirectToRouteResult gives me unlimited loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

```
public class UserFriendlyExceptionHandler : HandleErrorAttribute
    {
        public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {

...

var area = filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"];
var controller = filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
var action = filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
NameValueCollection queryString = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;

RouteValueDictionary redirectTargetDictionary = queryString.ToRouteValueDictionary();
redirectTargetDictionary.Add("area", area);
redirectTargetDictionary.Add("controller", controller);
redirectTargetDictionary.Add("action", action);

filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(redirectTargetDictionary);

...

}
```

when I am getting exception in update or insert I want to print this exception and redirect back to the same controller, but the problem is that `filterContext.Result` will be redirected back to the correct controller with query parameters also but I am getting unlimited loop. Back to controller and exception, back to controller and exception,...

why? How I can get back to controller if error is thrown?

Comment: If you redirect back to the same route with the same parameters then you will likely get the same error and get stuck in an infinite loop. What is your ultimate goal as obviously this will never work.

Comment: I want to get back to the same page but as GET not as POST. I want to show error on the same page.